# "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found" when opening PNG in Laravel

Tags: image, laravel, public

In my Laravel app, i have 2 PNGs uploaded in the public folder. One opens without problems:

https://www.josefabohemia.com/img/assets.png

And the other throws me the error:

https://www.josefabohemia.com/img/messenger.png

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your messenger.png doesn't exist : https://www.josefabohemia.com/img/

Comment: Well the link I gave you gives all the files in the directory and it doesn't show messenger.png

Comment: God i was uploading the file to a beta directory, how dumb can someone be?

Comment: Shit happens aha, by the way you should hide directory listing if you are in production